# How can I dump gem5 Ruby caches tags?

Tags: gem5

I'm using gem5 with ruby system -X86 with MESI_Two_Level.
I want to occasionally dump the L1 cache tags and flush the cache (every X instructions).
I understand that checkpointing won't work with MESI_Two_Level. Is there any other way to do so?
Thanks

I tried using the checkpoint mechanism in the end (--checkpoint-at-end) in se.py configuration but the gem5 crushes. that happens because I don't use MOESI hammer:
"While creating checkpoints with Ruby memory model, it is necessary to use the MOESI hammer protocol. This is because checkpointing the correct memory state requires that the caches are flushed to the memory. This flushing operation is currently supported only with the MOESI hammer protocol." - https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/checkpoints/

I only want to dump the tags and don't want to restore the state so maybe the checkpoint mechanism isn't the right one that suits my I want.
I don't want to use any debug flag because I want only the final state of the cache.